# Expression has changed after it was checked error triggered by Angular hidden directive

Tags: angular

I am getting an error:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

html

```
<div #visible >
    <div [hidden]="toInt(visible.style.width)<19"  >

    </div>
</div>
```

.ts

```
 toInt(x:string):number{
    return parseInt(x); 
  }
```

The usual medicine is to run change detection explicitly after the change.
But I am not changing any property in .ts file, so I dont know where to put

```
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the pain in a different scenario. A possible fix is

1. Access #visible in .ts `@ViewChild('visible') divElement: ElementRef;`
2. and in .ts

   ```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
          this._hideDiv= '<get the div length and do your condition>...'
   ```

   }
3. finally in your template `<div [hidden]="_hideDiv"> </div>`